# Проблема с визуальным редактором в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap, видео

Проблема следующая:
Натянута bootstrap тема на wordpress. На главной странице фоном стоит видео из локального файла.

```css
video{
   position:fixed;
   z-index:-1;
   min-width:100%;
   min-height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   top: -130px;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<video id="video_bg" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
     <source src="wp-content/uploads/2015/10/mount22.mp4" type="video/mp4" />&nbsp;
    </video>
```

При редактировании кода во встроенном текстовом редакторе Wordpress проблем нет, но после того, как сохраняешь изменения в визуальном редакторе, то в коде видео появляются `width=300` и `height=150`. После этого, понятно, видео сползает. 
Никакие плагины не установлены.

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в CSS строгие значения для width и height:

```css
video {
   position:fixed;
   z-index:-1;
   min-width:100%;
   width:100%;
   min-height:100%;
   height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   top: -130px;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что так как раз все сползает.
Я так понимаю, все из-за того, что у меня видео фоном сделано ужасными костылями. Если сможете с этим помочь, буду вам очень благодарен!

Comment: прописать width:100%; height:100%; пробовали? Если не получится то попробовать добавить !important